# Set child div with remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` with two child `div`s, one at the top and the other one at the bottom. The one at the top has a predefined height `20px` and the one at the bottom needs to have a height of the reminder of the container `div`, so I set it with `100%` however it seems to have the same height as the container div as it's pushed downward (see that the border of the container is hidden). How to fix this to have the bottom div spread to the remaining height, without specifying explicitly its height?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid black">
      <div style="width:100%;height:20px;background-color:gray">
        div 1
      </div>
       <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:orange">
        div 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc(100% - 20px)`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid black">
      <div style="width:100%;height:20px;background-color:gray">
        div 1
      </div>
       <div style="width:100%;height:calc(100% - 20px);background-color:orange">
        div 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Or flexbox with `flex-direction: column` and `flex-grow: 1` on the child you want to grow to fill the available space

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
      <div style="width:100%;height:20px;background-color:gray">
        div 1
      </div>
       <div style="width:100%;flex-grow:1;background-color:orange">
        div 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```